# databinding in c# acting oddly

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a question regarding my code:

I have a list of player "private List player = new List();" and Player is a class that I mad myself, I also created an Usercontrol and all variable of player are databinded.

And it's working perfectly fine in my main form, but I have a strange issue when I change form.

I give the player list as a parameter to another form and here is the code:

```
    public Result(List<Player> player, string format)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _player = player;
        ExtentionHelpers.Shuffle<Player>(_player);
    }
```

Shuffle as the name said, just shuffle the list, but it should shuffle _player which is a local variable of my second form, I never use player in this form.

But for some strange reason, my list player from my main form end up being shuffled too, and I don't want that, specially when that mess up my databinding.

What's happening here ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your player variable is a reference type, so it is the same data you are working on in both forms. You'll need to clone your player list if you want to manipulate it separately.

When calling your constructor, try this:

```
var frm = new Result(new List<Player>(player), "some format");
```

Creating a new list means that you can manipulate the new list independently from the first **BUT** if you change data within the `Player` type, it will affect data from the other form (you'll need to clone each item separately before adding to a new list if you want this).

Comment: Thanks, it's working now :D It created some other bugs but nothing I can't manage from now :)